# Multidimensional array is correct but return value is undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is a strange error and I don't understand where the problem is...

I have a function that create a multidimensional array:

```
  var array_eq = [];  //is global array

   //INSIDE FUNCTION
   var array_padre= [];
   for(var x= 0; x < another_array.length; x++){
    array_padre.push({ 
     idserial: another_array[x][0],
     milliseconds: (another_array[x][1]).toString(),                            
     latitude: (another_array[x][2]).toString(),                      
     longitude: (another_array[x][3]).toString()     
    });
   }
   array_eq.push(array_padre);
   //
```

If i use `console.log(array_eq)` this is **output**:

```
[
  [
    {
    "idserial": "2018-06-21-5070001-1081",
    "milliseconds": "1529615612000",
    "latitude": "-17.819",
    "longitude": "168.0229"
    },
    {
    "idserial": "2018-06-21-4760001-1087",
    "milliseconds": "1529610891000",
    "latitude": "0.5118",
    "longitude": "97.9914"
    }
  ]
]
```

if in my code, after `array_eq` was created, I write:

```
 alert(array_eq[0][0].idserial);
```

*RETURN*  **array_eq[0][0] is undefined**

I'm sure that alert is after creation of array...so what is the problem?

Comment: Please provide a more complete example. I assume you are trying to access the elements before the array is populated.

Comment: I am willing to bet this has nothing to do with the code shown and you are not showing the Ajax call and you are trying to eat the delivery pizza before it is delivered to your house.

Comment: yes the function is in ajax call but that not the problem. Trust in me...

Comment: "TRUST ME" Famous Last Words. It is the problem!

Comment: what is the value of array_eq[0]?

Comment: If you don't believe that ajax is the problem, [edit] your question to include what you've done to determine that it isn't the problem.